# How to search for post content and attached file names

Tags: search, attachments

I need to extend standard WP search functionality so that the search term is also applied to files attached to a post. In other words if user types in "annual report" then search results would include all pages and posts which have this search string in content and also in attached filename?

My current code is:

```
$search_list = array();

$search_query['s'] = $_GET['find'];
$search_query['post_type'] = array('post', 'page');
$search_query['post_status'] = 'publish';
$search_query['posts_per_page'] = '2';
$search_query['paged'] = get_query_var('paged');
$search_query['nopaging'] = false;

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, maybe you could look at the code for searching the media archive, hopefully that's well programmed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `$wpdb->posts` table in the database, you will notice that the file names, minus the file type ending, are used for the `post_title` for attachments. This means that you can effectively search the file name if you can get your search function to search attachments, which the default search (almost) already does.

In your code, these two lines are working against you...

```
$search_query['post_type'] = array('post', 'page');
$search_query['post_status'] = 'publish';
```

... because attachments are `'post_type' == 'attachments'` and `'post_status' == 'inherit'`.  If you alter the second of those to be ...

```
$search_query['post_status'] = array('publish','inherit);
```

... and leave off the first, you should have it working. That is...

```
$search_query['s'] = 'annual report';
$search_query['post_status'] = array('publish','inherit');
$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
var_dump($search);
```

You can also alter the global search with...

```
function search_attach_names_wpse_99832($qry) {
  if($qry->is_search()) {
    $qry->set('post_status',array('publish','inherit'));
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_attach_names_wpse_99832');
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I did get to the point of querying attachments, but how can I display parent post instead of the attachment post? The difficulty is that I need to filter out those results which come from the parent post content search. For example if I have phrase "annual accounts" both in attachments and post body then I want to display only one instance of parent post in search results.

Answer (score 0):

Search File name:

1. Add Filter

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse18703_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function wpse18703_posts_where( $where, $wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpse18703_title = $wp_query->get( 'wpse18703_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX( ' . $wpdb->posts . '.guid,"/", -1) LIKE "%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $wpse18703_title ) ) . '%"';
        var_dump($where);
    }
    
    return $where;
}
```

2. Use search

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'wpse18703_title' => $curYear,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'wpmf-category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $idFolderPresentations ,
            'include_children' => true
        )
    )
);
```